# Will a spambot be able to read this?

Tags: jquery, spam-prevention

As the title says, will this work in preventing a spam bot picking up the contact details:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.each($('.cd'), function(i,v){
        $(this).html($(this).attr('html'));
    });
});

<div style="display:table-cell" class="cd" html="0123456789"></div>
```

If not, are there any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Changed it. Does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite for doing this, is that: http://jsfiddle.net/ejwZJ/

Comment: ah... looks great. Can I combine my method and yours?

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks. Will see how this works. :) Thing is that value from in the html tag is read from a database, so will just check if there's a script to switch it around first.

Comment: Ah, PHP's [strrev](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) is the hero here...